# How to colour multiple geom_lines on a gradient using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61788948/how-to-change-the-colour-of-pdp-and-or-ice-plots-from-the-iml-package-in-r) with regard to how to colour a pdp-ice plot. I have since figured out a way to colour the plots by the predicted value. However, I am still having problems with how to manually select a colour gradient. I am using the `iml` package to create the predictions... but I feel that this is essentially a `ggplot2` problem, hence, I am opening a different question.

In the example below, I am creating a random forest model on the Boston data and using the rf model to create the ice-plot in `iml`.

```
library("iml")
library("randomForest")
library(ggplot2)

# We train a random forest on the Boston dataset:
data("Boston", package = "MASS")
rf = randomForest(medv ~ ., data = Boston, ntree = 50)
# Use iml to generate predictions
mod = Predictor$new(rf, data = Boston)
# Compute the individual conditional expectations for the feature room
ice = FeatureEffect$new(mod, method = 'ice', feature = "rm")
```

Now I could plot this using `plot(ice)` and this will create a ice plot with grey lines. However, I want to colour these lines on a gradient. I can colour them by the predicted values like so:

```
df <- ice$results
 ggplot(df, aes(x = rm, y = .value, color = .value)) + geom_line(aes(group = .id))
```

and this will produce a plot like this:
[image: ice plot]

Which is what I want (i.e., an ice plot colour gradient), but I can't figure out a way to manually set the colours of the plot... for example, if I wanted the low values to be red and high values to be blue. I have tried a few of the `ggplot2` options.. but I can't get them to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so,I solved this problem by using:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = rm, y = .value, color = .value )) + 
      geom_line(aes(group = .id)) +
       scale_colour_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "yellow", high = "blue", midpoint = 25)
```

Comment: My idea exactly. I had chosen a `midpoint = diff(range(df$.value))/2`.